# Calculate approximate value for a histogram bucket with for an `le` value that does not exists precisely?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have an application what produces histograms for prometheus:
(Java application using micrometer that automatically calculates the buckets).

Let's consider following buckets:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.001",} 0.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.005592405",} 0.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.134217727",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.268435456",} 4.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.357913941",} 7.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.447392426",} 9.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.536870911",} 9.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.626349396",} 9.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="0.7",} 9.0
http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status="200",uri="/hello",le="+Inf",} 9.0
http_server_requests_seconds_count{status="200",uri="/hello",} 9.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{status="200",uri="/hello",} 2.446759304
```

**I would like to get with promql the approximate value of bucket with `le=0.5`, this number of requests that are faster than 500ms.
How to do this in promql?**

I don't want to set the buckets manually, since this is not advised in micrometer documentation, also the query values might change (so I don't want to pre-configure the application).